# Swift considerable jump in tableview with just one query in cellforrow

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, realm, cell-formatting

I have the following code in my willDisplay:

```
func tableView(_: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        guard case let cell as L_LocCell = cell else {
            return
        }

        let subC = subContractors[indexPath.row]
        cell.backgroundColor = .clear
        cell.locName = subC.companyname
        cell.locCode = subC.region

        /*if let sType = Helper_Types.getType(subC.type)
        {
            cell.add = sType.name
        }
        else {
            cell.add = ""
        }*/

        switch subC.status {
        case 3:
            cell.catColor = UIColor(rgba: Palette.class_bad)

            cell.catName = "Declined"
            break
        case 2:
            cell.catColor = UIColor(rgba: Palette.class_good)
            cell.catName = "Approved"
            break
        case 1:
            cell.catColor = UIColor(rgba: Palette.class_warn)
            cell.catName = "Pending"
            break
        case 4:
            cell.catColor = UIColor(rgba: Palette.ok)
            cell.catName = "Approved with Exception"
            break
        default:
            cell.catColor = companyMed
            cell.catName = "Unknown"
            break
        }

        if subConPicDir != nil {
            let filename = subConPicDir!.appendingPathComponent(subC.subcontractorId.description+".jpg")
            cell.thumbImg.kf.setImage(
                with: filename,
                placeholder: UIImage(named: "ic_supplier")!,
                options: [.transition(.fade(1)), .cacheOriginalImage],
                progressBlock: { receivedSize, totalSize in

            },
                completionHandler: { result in
                    print(result)

            })
        }
        else{
            cell.thumbImg.image = UIImage(named: "ic_supplier")
        }

    }
```

There is a considerable difference in the smoothness of the scrolling when i put back in the commented out portion.

This is just a query to retrieve some info, i didn't have directly in my tableview's data source. How can I optimise this?

```
public static func getType(_ tid: Int) -> Types?
    {
        do {
            var realm : Realm? = try Realm()
            let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "_id = %d", tid);
            let types = realm!.objects(STD_type.self).filter(predicate);
            realm = nil
            if types.count > 0
            {
                return Types(st : types.first!)
            } else {
                return nil;
            }
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("error realm \(error.localizedDescription)")
            return nil
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Realm lookup is usually quite fast but it is still an async task which takes time and may even run on another thread.

Rather than doing this every time you attempt to render a cell I would suggest that you fetch all Types (maybe in viewDidLoad) and then just filter in `cellForRow`

Then you can just do something like

```
cell.add = types.first { $0.id == subC.type } ?? ""
```

Which is not aysnc and will be much faster and more responsive

If for some reason you can't fetch all types, I would at least cache the results as you get them.

Comment: to cache would I just add a property to cell called lets say subType: String? and then in cellForRow: if cell.subType == nil { cell.add = types.first({ $0.id == subC.type })?.name ?? ""; } else { cell.add = cell.type! }

Comment: if I wanted to do both, as there is still a slight jump with fetching all on viewdidload and retrieving like you have in your answer

Comment: How many types are there that you are fetching? and what do you mean by both? the call in viewDidLoad should be very fast and once you have the list there should be no more slowness

Comment: I meant both loading all at once, and also caching so the cellforrow doesn't have to filter down each time. But it is almost perfect now.

Comment: I have a similar issue with another tableview for equipment. where I would be loading up the assigned to employee in the cellforrow and I can have up to 10,000 employees so I wouldn't be able to load them all up in the viewDidLoad, what would you suggest for that? Even if caching wouldn't I still have the jumps on the initial scroll?